"Seagulls are gulling away."
A British speaker is walking around Brighton and talking about the town. At one point, he says:

I am just walking through all these lovely houses, and seagulls are gulling away.

Brighton (see:17:32-17:37)
Just to make sure the meaning of "to gull away", I looked it up, but couldn't find the meaning. Does it simply mean "Seagulls are chirping or singing".?

Seagulls mew or squawk. I would think that 'gulling' means 'doing what gulls do'. The use of away is idiomatic, though: continuously or repeatedly, or in a busy way.

There is a similar meme: "Cat's gonna cat."  Which means--just as Weather Vane said--"to do whatever cat's do."  See https://cheezburger.com/25192709/cats-gonna-cat-funny-memes-featuring-cats-engaging-in-behavior-of-the-cat-variety.  It's a form of word play, usually meant to be cute or amusing.  See https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-verbing-1691035. Using "google" as a verb is another example of using nouns as verbs (although that usage may be so entrenched these days that "google" is seen as a true verb in its own right).

"Flux capacitor... fluxing".

It's not a standard usage, but a whimsical invention. The speaker is using "gull," a noun, as if it were a verb* to describe the gulls' activity. This is sort of an instance of "verbing," like whimsical patterns like "I can't adult today" or "I won a Nobel prize for sciencing harder than the other sciencers." The intended meaning could be understood as "the seagulls are doing their thing."
It reminds me of this quasi-nonsense poem from The House at Pooh Corner:

NOISE, BY POOH
Oh, the butterflies are flying,
Now the winter days are dying,
And the primroses are trying
To be seen.
And the turtle-doves are cooing,
And the woods are up and doing,
For the violets are blue-ing
In the green.
Oh, the honey-bees are gumming
On their little wings, and humming
That the summer, which is coming,
Will be fun.
And the cows are almost cooing,
And the turtle-doves are mooing,
Which is why a Pooh is poohing
In the sun.
For the spring is really springing;
You can see a skylark singing,
And the blue-bells, which are ringing,
Can be heard.
And the cuckoo isn't cooing,
But he's cucking and he's ooing,
And a Pooh is simply poohing
Like a bird.

Pooh "verbs" his own name, "poohing," as the best way of expressing his feelings and describing his own activity of whimsical rhyming. (He also "verbs" an adjective in "the violets are blue-ing," and although "springing" is a real verb, he uses it more in the same way as "poohing," i.e. "spring is doing what spring does.")
This usage in the video, "seagulls are gulling," is paired with "away," used not in a prepositional sense that would mean "getting farther from me," but in a usage that pairs with a verb to mean "doing that verb right away, or enthusiastically, or uninterruptedly." E.g. "I gave the kid a crayon and he's just been drawing away for hours." See meaning 6 here.
* There is also a standard verb meaning for "gull," if a bit archaic, meaning to trick someone.

+1   Seagulls are being seagulls.

@TimR As, indeed, they always do.

Some asshole where I live ran over a beautiful gull. I am SO glad I didn't witness it. It's a part of the road where speed is limited.

I guess he was assholing...

@AndyBonner Excepting the exceptional Jonathan Livingston Seagull (dating myself there, I fear).

This poem makes me wonder if you can hear the difference between poohing and pooing...

@SpehroPefhany - I'll date myself too, then. Around 1980 I was visiting a socialist commune in Yorkshire  (England). Another visitor, an American feminist, (it turned out) had discarded her given name and surname and chosen  her own. Much respect all round, natch. 'Hi', she said to me, 'I'm Ocean Seagull'. 'Hi', I said back. 'How's your brother?'. 'My brother?' - 'Yes, Jonathan Livingston'.  I was the only person who thought that was funny!

There is a plague of seagulls in many UK coastal and near-coastal towns, and especially in Bristol, where I live. I use the word 'plague' deliberately. They flock in public areas, steal food out of people's hands, and attack people. Some town councils are using hawks to keep numbers down, and also remove eggs from any nests they can. On the other hand, an man aged 65 who killed a gull for stealing his fries was fined  £750 in costs and a £85 victim surcharge. ($1065 total) He was also sentenced to a 12-week curfew, applicable between the hours of 8pm and 8am, which began immediately.

@Stefan - when I was a boy, a polite childish word for 'shit' was 'pooh' spelt that way with an 'h'. The variant 'poo' is an extra-prissy, extra-infantile modern invention. They are pronounced the same. Likewise poohing/pooing. Also the Milne toy bear. Collins Dictionary gives 'pooh' as the main word, with 'poo' as a modern variant, and, interestingly, 'pugh' and 'puh' as archaic ones. I am advised that posh folks write 'pooh'.

@Stefan I’ve never seen poo spelled with an H. Perhaps so it doesn’t become a homophone, I pronounce the H in poohing, like in hang or hinge (although I don’t in Pooh). There’s no correct pronunciation, since it’s a made-up word. I suppose that’s not very consistent of me; the H in blahing is silent.

@Davislor - you really say 'poo-hing'? You're not joking? In the UK pooh with an h was the dominant form until maybe 1970 or a bit later.

@Davislor OED 2nd Ed: Pooh 2.B.2 slang. Excrement, faeces. Also transf. and fig.; in the pooh = in the shit s.v. shit n. 1 d.  1961 ‘You're rather in the pooh with the Adelaide police.’ ‘How much do I stink with them?’  1970 If they catch you with her, then you're really in the pooh.

@MichaelHarvey I say and spell pooing without an H, and if I were reading that one poem, the only place the nonce word ever appears, to a child, I would pronounce the H so it doesn’t sound like Winnie-the-Pooh is defecating. I’m American and am not familiar with that older British usage.

@Davislor How could you "pronounce the H" at the end? Phonemic /pu/ and so phonetic [pʰuw] or [pʰʊ̈ʉ̯] and such depending on transcription choices and perhaps on dialect, appear to admit no place at the end of the word to admit an additional [h] sound tacked on afterwards.

@tchrist I've never heard the "h" aspirated in either "pooh" or the "poohing" in this excerpt, including in audiobooks read by British actors. That is to say... I guess I do "sound like Winnie-the-Pooh is defecating." Crap, now if I ever have reason to read it out loud again I'm going to smirk...

@AndyBonner - I'm glad I'm not the only adult around here who has a mental age of around six!

@AndyBonner Learned in 1957 at the age of five, from a fellow pupil: Captain Cook did a pook, behind the cabin door. The cat came up, and licked it up, and said 'Mmmm! Can I have some more?'

@MichaelHarvey Rhyming pook with cook, hook not spook, kook is Quite Interesting™! Was that from a speaker of Scottish-, Irish-, or Northern-English (such as Mancunian or Lanky)? In places where the FOOT–STRUT split is absent and the FOOT–GOOSE merger present, the ‘short’ /ʊ/ of FOOT found in Southern England and almost all North America can become the ‘long’ /u/ of GOOSE.

There may also have been an additional joke of "gulling away" versus "going away", particularly if they're trying to pun on British rhotacism, where r's and w's get kind of blended.

@tchrist - that was the way people spoke in southern England --and still do-- the publicly run (municipal) school was in an inner-city borough of London (Lambeth) in an area called West Dulwich. The kids were predominantly 'Cockney', but we all said that vowel that way - look, book, cook, hook. took (and pook!). That 'spook/kook' thing is Northern (my wife is from Lancashire and she talks like that). I think they use it in Scotland too.

Oh. So that's the etymology of gullible

It's uncertain whether 'gull' meaning a 'mark' or easily-tricked person came from the seagull or derives from gullet -- either way it seems to have originally meant they'd swallow any story.

@NoName — you know, they took “gullible” out of the dictionary.

@MichaelLorton I'll have you know I always check the dictionary every morning precisely so I don't fall for that infantile trick. Wait...

@Michael  source?

@Harrychink — gotcha.

@michaellorton ???

@Harrychink — it’s a very old and, I fear, very childish joke.  One kid tells another “They took ‘gullible’ out of the dictionary” and the other responds by checking, or by asking about the situation, and thereby reveals himself as... gullible.

@michaellorton I don’t see how asking for a source is gullible

@Harrychink — because it’s an admission you regard this as within the realm of possibility.

@michael when you assume you make an ass out of you and me

Lately there has been an upswing in the whimsical nonce use of nouns as verbs meaning “being that thing” or “resembling that thing”.
I have heard “the math isn’t mathing” (meaning, the numbers are not adding up in the desired fashion) and “that movie 1990s so hard” (meaning, it displayed nostalgia for that time period).
It seems particularly prevalent on YouTube.

"Nonce"? I presume you mean 'nonsense'? Nonce is prison slang for a paedophile.

@Astralbee it's a also a technical term for a novel word or use of a word - Shakespeare was well known for his love of nonces
